# Как использовать setInterval для скрытия/показа div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

как сделать через `setInterval` так что-бы один .div исчезал (например через 5 секунд) и по исчезновению первого .div появился второй .div ну и т.д.

Comment: не хотите ли сделать это на CSS3?

Answer (score 2):

```js
console.info('Скрипт начнёт работать через 5 секунд');

var hideOne = setInterval(function(){
  $('.one').hide(function(){
    clearInterval(hideOne); // От повторного запуска
    
    console.info('Красный блок исчез, через 5 секунд появится синий блок');
    var showTwo = setInterval(function(){
      clearInterval(showTwo);
      $('.two').show();
    },1000*5); // 5 sec
  });
},1000*5); // 5 sec
```

```css
.one,
.two {
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

.one {
  background: red;
}

.two {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two" style="display: none;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> как сделать через setInterval так что-бы один .div исчезал (например через 5 секунд) и по исчезновению первого .div появился второй .div ну и т.д.

Вот так можно сделать, на `JS`:

```js
// Все квадраты
var boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box')
// Счетчик
var i = 0;
// Module
var mod = boxes.length
// Интервал в 5 сек
setInterval(() => {
  boxes[i % mod].classList.toggle('hide');
  boxes[++i % mod].classList.toggle('hide');
}, 5000);
```

```css
.one,
.two,
.three {
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

.one {
  background: red;
}

.two {
  background: blue;
}

.three {
  background: orange;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="box one "></div>
<div class="box two hide"></div>
<div class="box three hide"></div>
```